# Mysql2 and Rails on Windows

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So. I'm trying to develop a rails app, and I'm trying to do so in Windows 7. Here's what I've done:

1. Installed Ruby 1.9.3 using rubyinstaller
2. `gem update`
3. `gem install rails`
4. `gem update`
5. `rails new`
6. modified the gemfile, replace `sqlite3` with `mysql2`
7. modified database.yml correctly
8. `bundle install`
9. `gem update`
10. Added mysql to my path
11. Added a hardlink to the libmysql c connector in the ruby bin

Everything works so far, except when I do `rake db:create:all`, which results in:

```
rake aborted!
126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so
C:/Users/username/Documents/workspace/appname/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (
required)>'
C:/Users/username/Documents/workspace/appname/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

wtf?

UPDATE:

Full trace, by request:

```
rake aborted!
126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.
rb:2:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.
rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in
 `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in
 `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `
require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `
block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `
each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `
block in require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `
each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `
require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require
'
C:/Users/mschultz/Documents/workspace/recruit/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (
required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Users/mschultz/Documents/workspace/recruit/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `l
oad'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `l
oad_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `
raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `b
lock in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `
standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `l
oad_rakefile'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `b
lock in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `
standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `r
un'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>
'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: Can you post the trace? Also what does your gemfile look like?

Comment: Sure, if you think that will help, thank you for looking.

Comment: Have you tried specifying `gem "mysql2", "~> 0.2.7"` then running `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

Im using railsinstaller
solution: you have to add libmysql.dll to Ruby bin, btw its hint from bundle installator if you are creating app with --database=mysql parameter

Comment: Just copy libmysql.dll to Ruby bin. Fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I may recommend.

http://railsinstaller.org/

is the easiest way to get rails installed.  Just make sure it matches the correct system software.

However, I don't think it's your install. I think it's that you changed your DB.  Firstly, I'd recommend using PG, I think it's a lot better than sql2 or sql3.

However, given you want sql2 for some reason, I think your modified database.yml is off.  You stated it was correct, but you may want to double check it.

I'm not an expert, but maybe something was helpful here. Otherwise, good luck!

Comment: I also run this exact same rails code in MacOS, and on a Ubuntu based server (with a git repo), and it seems to be running just fine in both environments. I chose MySQL with the MySQL2 gem over postgres for its simplicity and my experience with it - not interested in switching to pg, and SQLite is not suitable for large-scale databases.

I also strongly prefer a manual rails install (gem install rails), as that makes it similar to the other systems.